# c# Select Single Item in Multiple Drop Down List in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, webbrowser-control, multipleselection

I've been searching for a solution for this problem, but have yet to find one that works.  I have a webBrowser control.  There is a multiple drop down list that is structured like this:

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" SELECTED>Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" SELECTED>Audi</option>
</select>

<p>Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.</p>
```

There are already some options selected.  I need to select one other option, such as "Volvo"
The typical was to do this would be to hold the ctrl key and right click on the option.  I was looking at the sendKeys class, but I'm not entirely sure I'm doing it right.
Here is what I have tried:

```
foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("option"))
{
    if (item.InnerText == "Volvo")
    {
        item.Focus();
        SendKeys.Send("^(+)");//sends ctrl-space
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to give the item focus, so I'm not sure if the SendKeys is working or not.

I also tried this :

```
foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("option"))
{
    if (item.InnerText == "Volvo")
    {
        item.SetAttribute("SELECTED", "");
    }
}
```

...but this does not seem to work either.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Update: this selects the item, but deselects all the other items in the process...    item.Parent.SetAttribute("value", "Volvo");

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm embarrassed to say that the answer was surprisingly simple...

Apparently the SetAttribute method does not take an empty string as a second argument.  This is the solution that worked:

```
foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("option"))
{
    if (item.InnerText == "Volvo")
    {
        item.SetAttribute("SELECTED", "SELECTED");
    }
}
```